# SQL search using 4 variables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to know is there any way to do a search of a table give 4 variable(columns), however of the 4, any or all variables can be activated to do the search, the issue is that if i am to write if statements depending on input's I would have 16 if functions (I wrote 4 if statements for my 2 variable problem)

Example:

I have a table called `cc_music` and it has 4 columns `track_name`, `artist`, `album` and `genre`.

Problem: the user is looking for a song. The user could enter all the 4 columns or, any 1 or none at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to structure your `WHERE` clause like this to allow for additive, but *"dynamic"* search criteria:

```
WHERE
     (@trackName IS NULL OR track_name = @trackName)
 AND (@artist IS NULL OR artist = @artist)
 AND (@album IS NULL OR album = @album)
 AND (@genre IS NULL OR genre = @genre)
```

You'll also want to consider revising this slightly to include partial matches like:

```
 AND (@artist IS NULL OR artist LIKE '%' + @artist + '%')
```

Just be careful of the performance implications of doing so with a large number of columns. Check your indexes!

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are using oracle sql

Use the following sql:

```
select * from cc_music where track_name like "%"||:track_name||"%" and artist like "%"||:artist||"%" and album like "%"||:album||"%" and genre like "%"||:genre||"%" ;
```

where : is the bind variable name.

no need for 16 different functions

Comment: I'm using Postgresql,and not oracle :)

Comment: you could have mentioned this earlier..:P